# PHP Undefined Index Error - Passing Value From Hidden Input

Tags: php, html

I am receiving this error when trying to pass a value via hidden input in a form. I have used this multiple times before, and I can't seem to figure out why it is not passing this time in particular.

Code from the form on index:

```
<form method="post" action="viewchars.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="uname" value="testuser" />
</form>
```

Code on viewchars.php:

```
<?php
    $user = $_POST["uname"];
?>
```

The error states that uname is the undefined index.

I am not trying to get the error to just go away, as I actually need the value being passed for the viewchars.php page.

Comment: this should work. Where is your submit button?

Comment: Ah! You see no submit button because there is no submit button...
You do see the problem however!

Thank you user!

Comment: should work, agree. What happens if the input is made visible? Do you also have a submit button?

Comment: What happens if you add the submit button and try with that?

Comment: how you are submitting that form? If its not present then probably here is problem - anyways you should check if value exists and handle situation when it is not present (like `$user = isset($_POST['uname']) ? $_POST['uname'] : null;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add submit button in your html

```
<form method="post" action="viewchars.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="uname"  value="testuser" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure the form is submitted before using POST values. So it should be something like

`$user = isset($_POST['uname']) ? $_POST['uname'] : '';`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending this via JS make sure you are actually using POST. Have you tried to test on $_REQUEST, instead?

Also, try:

- use a submit button just to test
- make the input visible and type text to test
- change var name
- try a print_r($_REQUEST); on the php side to see what is received

Answer (score 0):

just remove "/" form end of input line! 
like this...

`<form method="post" action="viewchars.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="uname" value="testuser" >
</form>`

Answer (score -1):

try the following:

```
$user = $_POST['uname'];
```

Comment: Single or double quotes makes no difference.